# Phantom Pending Reboot causing SCCM Updates to fail

Tags: sccm

Has anyone else encountered this problem:

Every month I apply windows updates to servers using SCCM Software Update Groups.  Some servers are considered lower priority so I push the updates as required to the server and expect the updates to install and the server to reboot if necessary during its assigned maintenance window only to find out that the some of the updates are failing.  With experience, I have found this is because the system is waiting for a reboot.  I would expect that SCCM would know that there is a pending reboot and reboot the server during the maintenance window to finish applying the updates but it does not.  It seems as though these are "pending reboots" that SCCM cannot detect.

As a result, this requires manual intervention each month on a dozen or more servers that have to be manually rebooted in the middle of the night so as to not interrupt production.

One of the biggest culprits to this issue is the monthly Malicious Software Removal Tool.  It always seems to fail to apply then works after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The Computer Restart related setting can be configured in the "Client Setting" node on your console. No matter if you determine to use the Default client setting or the custom client settings, you should make sure that that the value for the **restart temporary notification interval** and the value for the f**inal countdown interval** are **shorter** in duration than the shortest maintenance window that is applied to the computer (the default values are 90 and 15 mins). This is important for the deployments which require a reboot completed on your clients.

Additionally, you can examine the logs on the client-side as below:

- Update deployments related logs: **UpdatesDeployment.log**, **WindowsUpdate.log**
- Reboot & Maintenance related logs:**RebootCoordinator.log**,**ServiceWindowManager.log**

More details about how to track the Update deployment process in ConfigMgr can be found [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/configmgrdogs/2014/06/29/configmgr-2012-windows-update-client-process/).